# Reference a of list values in R in a sql chunk

Tags: sql, r, r-markdown

I want to reference a list of values to be used in a sql chunk.

I have tried using the dplyr::translate_sql function to convert the list to a correct syntax, but it doesn't seem to be correct. I can copy and paste the output of the translate_sql object and it will run, but I cannot embed thoe object.

values <- translate_sql(c("value1", "value2", "value3"))

print(values)

```
<SQL> ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
```

```
select *
from db.table
where column in ?values
```

I get an error message saying the syntax is incorrect.

However if I just copy and paste the values (See code below, it runs perfectly)

```
select *
from db.table
where column in ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
```

Comment: What R code have you tried and what was the error message?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near '('VALUE001', 'VALUE002', 'VALUE003', 'VALUE004', 'VALUE007', 'VALUE008', 'VALUE009', 'VALUE011', 'VALUE012', 'VALUE013')'

Also, I am trying the run the query in a sql chunk in Rmarkdown

Comment: This could be helpful: https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/sql-translation.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have already gone through the page previously.

Answer (score 2):

After much pain, this blog solved this problem for me:
https://irene.rbind.io/post/using-sql-in-rstudio/#passing-variables-tofrom-sql-chunks
"Adding an * to the end of the variable collapses the vector into a single comma-separated expression, rather than outputting a vector of SQL expressions."

```
values<-glue::glue_sql("{myrvariable*}", .con = con)
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE column IN (?values)
```

Comment: It's helpful if you include a small summary of the resource you're linking in the answer. This makes it searchable and prevents dead links.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the query as a string:

```
sql <- translate_sql(c("value1", "value2", "value3"))

query <- paste(
    "select *
from db.table
where column in",
    as.character(sql)
)

# or

glue::glue("select *
from db.table
where column in {as.character(sql)}")
```

It will be translated into

```
>writeLines(query)
select *
from db.table
where column in ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
```

Comment: This works but is it possible to pass the vector directly into the query?

Rather than 
```select *
from db.table
where column in ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
```
Pass the vector directly into the query.
```select *
from db.table
where column in ?vector_name
```

Comment: Just modified my answer, by using `glue`, it's similar to boshek's answer.

Comment: Again, this works as it creates a sql string that I can run. However, the code gets messy if I need to repeat it for multiple columns. 
```column in ('value1', 'value2', 'value3') or column2 in ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')``` etc. 

Using the sql code chunk in R markdown, is it possible to pass a list into it so the code isn't as messy?

```
{sql query, connection = conn, output.var = 'df'}
select *
from db.table
where (column1 in ?values
or column2 in ?values
or column3 in ?values)
```

Comment: Yes, use `glue` function in `glue` package where you can have placeholder variables inside `{}`. Please see boshek's and my answer.

Comment: I see what you mean, but when I try to run the query using glue, i still get an incorrect syntax error.

Comment: We can't help you unless you can provide an example where we can reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

A handy function for this is `glue_sql` which works like this:

```r
library(glue)
library(dbplyr)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
colnames(iris) <- gsub("[.]", "_", tolower(colnames(iris)))
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "iris", iris)

values <- translate_sql(c("value1", "value2", "value3"))

glue_sql("select *
         from db.table
         where column in {values}",
         .con = con)
#> <SQL> select *
#> from db.table
#> where column in '(''value1'', ''value2'', ''value3'')'
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I gave this a try and am unfortunately still getting the same syntax error.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near '(' 'VALUE001', 'VALUE002', 'VALUE003' ')'